# Solana showing wrong timestamp for Testnet Transactions

Tags: blockchain, solana, solana-web3js, solana-cli

I was developing my crypto-based project using the Solana blockchain. I did all the operations using Solana's **Devnet** < Solana Developer Network >. Recently I switched to Solana **Testnet** and when I try to fetch details of the transaction signature using their API or solscan.io. It is showing a **wrong timestamp** < 7 days ago, 14 days ago, etc.. > for the transaction.

Any idea about this?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: you could ask you r question here: https://solana.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testnet was down for over two weeks, so the timestamp will take some time for the cluster to correct.